# NULL vs throw and performance

Tags: c++, performance, exception, null

I have a class:

```
class Vector {
    public:
    element* get(int i);
    private:
    element* getIfExists(int i):
};
```

`get` invokes `getIfExists`; if element exists, it is returned, if not, some action is performed. `getIfExists` can signal that some element `i` is not present
either by throwing exception, or by returning NULL.

Question: would there be any difference in performance? In one case, `get` will need to check `==NULL`, in another `try... catch`.

Comment: I don't think you're asking the right question. The difference is in how the program that uses the class is written, and how are you handling errors and exceptions, as a whole. This particular detached function is meaningless.

Comment: I typically have a `find` and `get` function, for convenience. The `find` function has optional semantics (in the case of a reference return value, a pointer that can be null, or in the case of a value return value, `boost::optional`). The `get` function is just like `find`, except it removes the optional semantics and throws if the element doesn't exist. Then I just use `find` if non-existence is expected, and `get` if existence is expected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its a matter of design, not performance. If its an exceptional situation -like in your `get` function- then throw an exception; or even better fire an assert since violation of a function precondition is a programming error. If its an expected case -like in your `getIfExist` function- then don't throw an exception.

Regarding performance, zero cost exception implementations exist (although not all compilers use that strategy). This means that the overhead is only paid when an exception its thrown, which should be... well... exceptionally.

Answer (score 3):

(See comments!)

Without a doubt the `return NULL` variant has a better performance.

You should mostly never use exceptions when using return values is possible too.
Since the method is named `get` I assume NULL won't be a valid result value, so passing NULL should be the best solution.
If the caller does not test the result value, it dereferences a null value, rendering a SIGSEGV, what is appropriate too.

If the method is rarely called, you should not care about micro optimizations at all.

Which translated method looks easier to you?

$ g++ -Os -c test.cpp

```
#include <cstddef>

void *get_null(int i) throw ();
void *get_throwing(int i) throw (void*);

int one(int i) {
    void *res = get_null(i);
    if(res != NULL) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int two(int i) {
    try {
        void *res = get_throwing(i);
        return 1;
    } catch(void *ex) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

$ objdump -dC test.o

```
0000000000000000 <one(int)>:
   0:   50                      push   %rax
   1:   e8 00 00 00 00          callq  6 <one(int)+0x6>
   6:   48 85 c0                test   %rax,%rax
   9:   0f 95 c0                setne  %al
   c:   0f b6 c0                movzbl %al,%eax
   f:   5a                      pop    %rdx
  10:   c3                      retq   

0000000000000011 <two(int)>:
  11:   56                      push   %rsi
  12:   e8 00 00 00 00          callq  17 <two(int)+0x6>
  17:   b8 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%eax
  1c:   59                      pop    %rcx
  1d:   c3                      retq   
  1e:   48 ff ca                dec    %rdx
  21:   48 89 c7                mov    %rax,%rdi
  24:   74 05                   je     2b <two(int)+0x1a>
  26:   e8 00 00 00 00          callq  2b <two(int)+0x1a>
  2b:   e8 00 00 00 00          callq  30 <two(int)+0x1f>
  30:   e8 00 00 00 00          callq  35 <two(int)+0x24>
  35:   31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
  37:   eb e3                   jmp    1c <two(int)+0xb>
```

Comment: The exception could be caught higher up the call stack, allowing the direct caller to rely on validity of the return value and optimize the common case. Also, checking for NULL incurs a misprediction when the value is valid, which could cost tens of cycles

Comment: @DonReba, profiling seems to confirm your hypothesis on a Intel Core 2. The try-catch variant is on average 3.5 % faster than the compare against zero variant in a tight loop. (10 measures of 1,000,000,000 iterations, each.)

Answer (score 3):

Modern compilers implement 'zero cost' exceptions - they only incur cost when thrown, and the cost is proportional to the cleanup plus the cache-miss to get the list to clean up.  Therefore, if exceptions are exceptional, they can indeed be faster than return-codes.  And if they are unexceptional, they may be slower.  And if your error is in a function in a function in a function call, it actually do much less work throwing.  The details are fascinating and well worth googling.

But the cost is very marginal.  In a tight loop it might make a difference, but generally not.

You should write the code that is easiest to reason about and maintain, and then ***profile*** it and revisit your decision only if its a bottleneck.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there would be a difference in performance: returning NULL is less expensive than throwing an exception, and checking for NULL is less expensive than catching an exception.

**Addendum:** But performance is only relevant if you expect that this case will happen frequently, in which case it's probably not an exceptional case anyway. In C++, it's considered bad style to use exceptions to implement normal program logic, which this seems to be: I'm assuming that the point of `get` is to auto-extend the vector when necessary?

Comment: On the other hand, checking for NULL might be more expensive than *not* catching an exception.

Answer (score 1):

There will certainly be a difference in performance (maybe even a very big one if you give `Vector::getIfExists` a `throw()` specification, but I 'm speculating a bit here). But IMO that's missing the forest for the trees.

The money question is: **are you going to call this method so many times with an out-of-bounds parameter? And if yes, why?**

Answer (score 1):

If the caller is going to be expecting to deal with the possibility of an item not existing, you should return in a way that indicates that without throwing an exception.  If the caller is not going to be prepared, you should throw an exception.  Of course, the called routine isn't likely to magically know whether the caller is prepared for trouble.  A few approaches to consider:

1. Microsoft's pattern is to have a Get() method, which returns the object if it exists and throws an exception if it doesn't, and a TryGet() method, which returns a Boolean indicating whether the object existed, and stores the object (if it exists) to a Ref parameter.  My big complaint with this pattern is that interfaces using it cannot be covariant.

   A variation, which I often prefer for collections of reference types, is to have Get and TryGet methods, and have TryGet return null for non-existent items.  Interface covariance works much better this way.

   A slight variation on the above, which works even for value-types or unconstrained generics, is to have the TryGet method accept a Boolean by reference, and store to that Boolean a success/fail indicator.  In case of failure, the code can return an unspecified object of the appropriate type (most likely default<T>.

   Another approach, which is particularly suitable for private methods, is to pass either a Boolean or an enumerated type specifying whether a routine should return null or throw an exception in case of failure.  This approach can improve the quality of generated exceptions while minimizing duplicated code.  For example, if one is trying to get a packet of data from a communications pipe and the caller isn't prepared for failure, and an error occurs in a routine that reads the packet header, an exception should probably be thrown by the packet-header-read routine.  If, however, the caller will be prepared not to receive a packet, the packet-header-read routine should indicate failure without throwing.  The cleanest way to allow for both possibilities would be for the read-packet routine to pass an "errors will be dealt with by caller" flag to the read-packet-header routine.

   In some contexts, it may be useful for a routine's caller to pass a delegate to be invoked in case anticipated problems arise.  The delegate could attempt to resolve the problem, and do something to indicate whether the operation should be retried, the caller should return with an error code, an exception should be raised, or something else entirely should happen.  This can sometimes be the best approach, but it's hard to figure out what data should be passed to the error delegate and how it should be given control over the error handling.

In practice, I tend to use #2 a lot.  I dislike #1, since I feel that the return value of a function should correspond with its primary purpose.